# Flutter error: The argument type 'List<dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Movie>'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

The argument type 'List?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful to see your code so that I can offer the exact answer but as the error says, you're basically trying to assign a nullable list to a List variable that expects elements of Movie type.

This is because of however you're passing values into the variable that expects a List.

Since I don't have your code on hand, here are some scenarios that can illustrate this:

```
List? a;
List<Movie> b = a;
```

This basically leads to the exact error you're seeing.

```
void fooBar(List? a) {
  List<Movie> b = a;
}
```

Same error.

You need to be explicit with the value that's being passed into your original List field, no matter where it's coming from.

So you need to make sure that a, in the above examples, is a `List<Movie>`. This kind of error can often happen in the second scenario above, where you have some method with an argument that's not been setup as a strict type (resulting in dynamic) and with any value/you marking it as nullable (resulting in the List? complaint).

Hope that helps! Leave a comment with your code example if you need more explicit help!